# How can I export data from listview(sqllite database) to txt file?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have data from the SQLite database and displayed it in the listview of Xamarin Forms. Now I want to export what's on my listview to a txt file on a particular Location.

I have been searching on the internet but not getting any proper solution on it.

This is the source for my binding.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinSQLite"
         x:Class="XamarinSQLite.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Image x:Name="imgBanner" Source="banner.png" ></Image>
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,10" HeightRequest="100" Source="SQLite.png" ></Image>
            <Label Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="SQLite" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" ></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="txtPersonId" Placeholder="PersonId Update and Delete"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="txtName" Placeholder="Enter Person Name"></Entry>
            <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnAdd" WidthRequest="200" Text="Add" Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked" />
                <Button x:Name="btnRead" WidthRequest="200" Text="Read" Clicked="BtnRead_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" WidthRequest="200" Text="Update" Clicked="BtnUpdate_Clicked"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnDelete" WidthRequest="200" Text="Delete" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" />
                <Button x:Name="btnExport" WidthRequest="200" Text="Export" Clicked="btnExport_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lstPersons">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding PersonID}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinSQLite
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        
            //Get All Persons
            var personList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
            if(personList!=null)
            {
                lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
            }
        }

        private async void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
            {
                Person person = new Person()
                {
                    Name = txtName.Text
                };

                //Add New Person
                await App.SQLiteDb.SaveItemAsync(person);
                txtName.Text = string.Empty;
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person added Successfully", "OK");
                //Get All Persons
                var personList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
                if (personList != null)
                {
                    lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter name!", "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void BtnRead_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
            {
                //Get Person
                var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));
                if(person!=null)
                {
                    txtName.Text = person.Name;
                    await DisplayAlert("Success","Person Name: "+ person.Name, "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter PersonID", "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void BtnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
            {
                Person person = new Person()
                {
                    PersonID=Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text),
                    Name = txtName.Text
                };

                //Update Person
                await App.SQLiteDb.SaveItemAsync(person);

                txtPersonId.Text = string.Empty;
                txtName.Text = string.Empty;
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Updated Successfully", "OK");
                //Get All Persons
                var personList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
                if (personList != null)
                {
                    lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter PersonID", "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPersonId.Text))
            {
                //Get Person
                var person = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtPersonId.Text));
                if (person != null)
                {
                    //Delete Person
                    await App.SQLiteDb.DeleteItemAsync(person);
                    txtPersonId.Text = string.Empty;
                    await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Deleted", "OK");
                
                    //Get All Persons
                    var personList = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
                    if (personList != null)
                    {
                        lstPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Required", "Please Enter PersonID", "OK");
            }
        }

        private void btnExport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       //How to Export Data In Txt file
        }
    }
}
```

**Please Help Me I am new in Xamarin**

Comment: What are you stuck with though? You can write text files with a single line of code - `File.WriteAllText(fileName, textYouWantInTheFile);`- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: (It's a bit confusing that creating a UI, download data from a database etc is something you can do, but looking up the documentation for how to use one line of code to write a file is something you cannot do - explain more what you're struggling with (and don't say "the whole thing" because that just reads like "I want someone to do my [home]work for me") - were a help site not a free freelancer site)

Comment: I just want a code through which I can export a text file on button click to a particular location or folder from list view of xamarin

Comment: Yea, I know what you want. I'm trying to explain that the effort of learning and doing it yourself is less than the effort you've put so far into writing a question asking someone else to do it for you.. it really is one line of code to write a file, and another line maybe to loop over the listview and pull text out of it.. Show some attempt at doing it yourself, even if you get it wrong; it'll make your question less of a "I want someone to do my work for me"/giv me teh codez

Comment: sir I already try to do that but I don't know why its not working that's why I ask this question

Comment: You seem to have pasted your entire program into the question, but not a single line of it looks to make any attempt at writing a file. I may have missed it in the middle of sll the irrelevant code but all I found was an empty button click handler. "I searched the internet but found nothing" isn't credible either; I searched the internet for "Xamarin write text file" and hit the official docs, which I linked to you, as the top hit. The documentation includes example code for writing a file, and it really is just a single line of code

Comment: what I want is when I click on the extract button a new text file should be created and saved in a particular folder where I want. in sample code, it just shows how to write text in a text file.

Comment: You just need export the data to a file or you need the file content like the listview display ?